# Full Stop / Period in URL does not allow Redirect

Tags: iis, azure

I'm using a basic Azure Web App to redirect all requests from one domain to another.

I have the following in my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://domain.foo.com$V$Q" exactDestination="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

All URLs work but one we use infrequently has a "." halfway through the URL.

Such as "https://originaldomain.foo.com/request/requestparam.svc/anotherparam

This throws a 404.

I've found many examples on the line for adding

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

But this does not work within Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I raised this with Microsoft and they stated it was not possible in Azure due to file access limitations in Azure Web Sites & Services. They suggested I ran IIS in a standalone VM.

I decided to run this domain forward on Apache instead and it works a treat!